# Pandas - using assign and if-else statement in method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dplyr, method-chaining

I come from an R background and I'm trying to replicate the `mutate()` function from dplyr in pandas.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

I am now trying to create a new column called `age_bracket` using `assign` method as follows:

```
(df.
    assign(age_bracket= lambda x: "under 25" if x['age'] < 25 else
        ("25-34" if x['age'] < 35 else "35+"))
```

And this is throwing the following error which I'm not able to understand:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

I am not interested the following solution:

```
df['age_bracket'] = np.where(df.age < 25, 'under 25',
     (np.where(df.age < 35, "25-34", "35+")))
```

As I do not want the underlying df to change. I'm trying to get better at method chaining where I can quickly explore my df in different ways without changing the underlying df.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.assign(age_bracket=np.where(df.age < 25, 'under 25', (np.where(df.age < 35, "25-34", "35+"))))`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible, but not recommended, because loops (under the hood of `apply` function):

```
df = (df.
    assign(age_bracket= lambda x: x['age'].apply(lambda y: "under 25" if y < 25 else
        ("25-34" if y < 35 else "35+"))))
print (df)
    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore age_bracket
0  Jason   42             4             25         35+
1  Molly   52            24             94         35+
2   Tina   36            31             57         35+
3   Jake   24             2             62    under 25
4    Amy   73             3             70         35+
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = df.assign(age_bracket= np.select([df.age < 25,df.age < 35], ['under 25', "25-34"], "35+"))
```

But better is use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) here:

```
df = (df.assign(age_bracket= lambda x: pd.cut(x['age'], 
                                              bins=[0, 25, 35, 150],
                                              labels=["under 25", "25-34", "35+"])))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will explore 'cut' more. Can you please help me understand why we need `apply` inside `assign`?

Comment: Thanks also for a working example on `cut`. Would you say `cut` is faster method here than apply?

Comment: @RachitKinger - In my opinion yes, but depends of data, number of rows, number of bins. 
The best test in real data.

Comment: Yep. `pd.cut` is particularly neat for grouping numeric values into (ordered) categoricals (e.g. satisfaction level/difficulty/age bucket). Good job!

Answer (score 9):

Why not use assign with np.where?

```
df.assign(age_bracket = np.where(df.age < 25, 'under 25',
     (np.where(df.age < 35, "25-34", "35+"))))
```

You are returned a copy of the original dataframe with new column.

But I agree with @jezrael `pd.cut` is better my opinion.

Output:

```
    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore age_bracket
0  Jason   42             4             25         35+
1  Molly   52            24             94         35+
2   Tina   36            31             57         35+
3   Jake   24             2             62    under 25
4    Amy   73             3             70         35+
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy to use the same syntax in python as you did in R, using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, mutate, if_else
>>> 
>>> data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
...         'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
...         'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
...         'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(**data)
>>> df >> mutate(age_bracket=if_else(
...   f.age < 25, 
...   "under 25",
...   if_else(f.age < 35, "25-34", "35+")
... ))
      name     age  preTestScore  postTestScore age_bracket
  <object> <int64>       <int64>        <int64>    <object>
0    Jason      42             4             25         35+
1    Molly      52            24             94         35+
2     Tina      36            31             57         35+
3     Jake      24             2             62    under 25
4      Amy      73             3             70         35+
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Answer (score 0):

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) has a [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.case_when.html#janitor.case_when) implementaton in `dev` that could be helpful in this case, the implementation idea is inspired by [if_else](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/ifelse.html) in `pydatatable` and [fcase](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fcase) in R's `data.table`; under the hood, it uses [pd.Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

df.case_when(
   df.age.lt(25), 'under 25',  # 1st condition, result
   df.age.lt(35), '25-34',    # 2nd condition, result
   '35+',                     # default
   column_name = 'age_bracket')

    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore age_bracket
0  Jason   42             4             25         35+
1  Molly   52            24             94         35+
2   Tina   36            31             57         35+
3   Jake   24             2             62    under 25
4    Amy   73             3             70         35+
```

For this use case though, since you are partitioning on categories, `pd.cut` solution by @jezrael is more efficient.