# how to make col2 the cumsum of the second col1 == 'x' in DateTime per group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, cumsum

I would like a column in a `pandas` `dataframe` that

- counts the number of times `'outcome2'` is observed in `'value'` through `'datetime'`
- starting from the second observation of `'outcome2'`
- per `'ID'` or `df.index`

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import datetime 

txt= """
ID,datetime,value
A,12/10/2022 10:00:00,outcome1
A,12/10/2022 11:15:10,outcome2
A,14/10/2022 15:30:30,outcome1
B,11/10/2022 11:30:22,outcome1
B,15/10/2022 22:44:11,outcome2
B,15/10/2022 23:30:22,outcome3
B,15/10/2022 23:31:11,outcome2
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt),\
             parse_dates=[1],\
             dayfirst=True)\
             .assign(id_index= lambda x_df: x_df\
             .groupby('ID', sort=False).ngroup())\
             .set_index("id_index")\
             .rename_axis(index=None)

df = df.assign(value_test = lambda df: df['value']=='outcome2',\
               value_cumsum= lambda df: df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['value_test'].cumsum())

  ID            datetime     value value_test   value_cumsum
0  A 2022-10-12 10:00:00  outcome1      False              0
0  A 2022-10-12 11:15:10  outcome2       True              1
0  A 2022-10-14 15:30:30  outcome1      False              1
1  B 2022-10-11 11:30:22  outcome1      False              0
1  B 2022-10-15 22:44:11  outcome2       True              1
1  B 2022-10-15 23:30:22  outcome3      False              1
1  B 2022-10-15 23:31:11  outcome2       True              2
```

I tried assigning a third variable to `df` using if-statements in the `lambda` functions. It failed in a way others have experienced [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609780/pandas-using-assign-and-if-else-statement-in-method-chaining). **edit** now it works, but is not neat:

```py
df = df.assign(value_test = lambda df: df['value']=='outcome2',\
               value_cumsum = lambda df: df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['value_test'].cumsum(),\
               outcome2 = lambda df: 0 if df[df[value_cumsum]==1] or df[df[value_cumsum]==0]\
               else df[value_cumsum]-1 if df[df[value_cumsum] > 1]

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

# edit:
df = df.assign(value_test = lambda df: df['value']=='outcome2',\
               cumsum = lambda df: df.groupby('ID', sort=False)\
                        ['value_test'].cumsum(),\
               outcome2 = lambda df:df['cumsum'].apply(\
                          lambda cumsum: 0 if cumsum == 1\
                                 else (0 if cumsum == 0\
                                 else (cumsum-1 if cumsum > 1\
                                 else 'NaN'))))
```

I need *only* the accumulated sum (running total) of counts of `'outcome2'` in `'value'` starting from the second observation of `'outcome2'` per group.*

Any suggestions, please?

And *is it possible to solve without the intermediate step making `value_test` or `value_cumsum`*?

*desired df*

```py
  ID            datetime     value outcome2
0  A 2022-10-12 10:00:00  outcome1        0
0  A 2022-10-12 11:15:10  outcome2        0
0  A 2022-10-14 15:30:30  outcome1        0
1  B 2022-10-11 11:30:22  outcome1        0
1  B 2022-10-15 22:44:11  outcome2        0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:30:22  outcome3        0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:31:11  outcome2        1
```

Comment: it is not completely clear what you mean by "I would like a column". Aren't you looking for just one number, namely the count of "outcome2"? Please include an example table with your desired output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I will make sure to highlight the bottom table as the desired output. And no, I am not looking for one number. I am looking for a column with one number in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['value_cumsum'] = (df.groupby('ID')['value_test']
                      .cumsum().sub(1).where(df['value_test'], 0)
                      )
```

Or, if you also want to label the False:

```
df['value_cumsum'] = (df.groupby('ID')['value_test']
                      .cumsum().sub(1).clip(lower=0)
                      )
```

output:

```
  ID            datetime     value  value_test  value_cumsum
0  A 2022-10-12 10:00:00  outcome1       False             0
0  A 2022-10-12 11:15:10  outcome2        True             0
0  A 2022-10-14 15:30:30  outcome1       False             0
1  B 2022-10-11 11:30:22  outcome1       False             0
1  B 2022-10-15 22:44:11  outcome2        True             0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:30:22  outcome3       False             0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:31:11  outcome2        True             1
```

##### without intermediate:

```
df['value_cumsum'] = (df['value'].eq('outcome2')
                      .groupby(df['ID'])
                      .cumsum().sub(1).clip(lower=0)
                     )
```

output:

```
  ID            datetime     value  value_cumsum
0  A 2022-10-12 10:00:00  outcome1             0
0  A 2022-10-12 11:15:10  outcome2             0
0  A 2022-10-14 15:30:30  outcome1             0
1  B 2022-10-11 11:30:22  outcome1             0
1  B 2022-10-15 22:44:11  outcome2             0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:30:22  outcome3             0
1  B 2022-10-15 23:31:11  outcome2             1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind adding some explanation to `.sub(1).where(df['value_test'], 0)` and `.sub(1).clip(lower=0)`? And do you have any insights to share about why not to use `lambda`?

Comment: You want to label from the second, this means you can label from the first and subtract 1. Thus 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1 etc. The `where` is used to mask the `False` rows with 0. Or if you want to keep the numbering for the `False` rows, `clip` ensures you have no negative values by setting the minimum value to 0

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How about that `lambda` function; any thoughts on that? The solution you suggest uses the `value_test` I tried. Are you able to see how to solve the problem without that intermediate helper variable?

Comment: Ah, sorry. That edit did not provide a solution; so I wasn't clear enough. I tried to ask: Are you able to develop `value_cumsum` in your initial solution (`òutcome2` in my `desired df`) without generating other helper variables using _just_ the original `df` with `'index'`, `'ID'`, `'datetime'`, and `'value'`?

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: I see that your second solution actually answers my follow-up question. But the output does not show it. I currently cannot edit your answer, but I would if I could, to make sure the solution and the output correspond. Thanks!

Comment: fyi, I found out this way to use `lambda`, which is surely horrible in comparison to yours: `df = df.assign(value_test = lambda df: df['value']=='outcome2',\
                  cumsum = lambda df: df.groupby('ID', sort=False)['value_test'].cumsum(),\
                  outcome2 = lambda df: df['cumsum'].apply(lambda cumsum: 0 if cumsum == 1 else\
                                                       (0 if cumsum == 0 else\
                                                        (cumsum-1 if cumsum > 1 else 'NaN'))))`